# SelectionTracker drag to select doesn't work for RecyclerView inside a NestedScrollView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

#### Expected behaviour:

Tap and hold to start a selection with `SelectionTracker` then drag to select more items.

#### Actual behaviour:

One item gets selected, then `NestedScrollView` starts intercepting touch events, making drag to select not work. User sees the overscroll stretch effect.

#### Layout from top-down:

- `CoordinatorLayout` (with an `AppBarLayout`)
- `ViewPager2`
- `NestedScrollView` (needed, because we have a `ViewPager2`)
- `RecyclerView` (with `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"`)

Answer (score 0):

We'll fix this by preventing the parent `NestedScrollView` from intercepting touch events when action mode is first opened. We allow it every other time (when action mode is closed or when the user is tapping down the second time).

```kotlin
//Your existing state variable. Probably a MutableStateFlow.
var actionModeOpened = false

//Whether we allow parent NestedScrollView to intercept touch events or not
var dissalow = false

recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(object : RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        val down = e.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
        if(down && selectionTracker!!.hasSelection()) {
            //Second down event, we now enable NestedScrollView
            dissalow = false
        }

        parentNestedScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(dissalow)

        if(!down || !selectionTracker!!.hasSelection()) {
            return false //Don't intercept or you'll break scrolling
        }

        //Fix for https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177046288 (click on background)
        //and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187339902 (click on ItemDivider)
        val view = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.x, e.y)
        return view == null
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(rv: RecyclerView, e: MotionEvent) { }
    override fun onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(disallowIntercept: Boolean) { }
})

//Initialize SelectionTracker here
selectionTracker = SelectionTracker.Builder(...)

//Probably your existing code to track whether action mode is opened or closed
selectionTracker!!.addObserver(object : SelectionTracker.SelectionObserver<Long>() {
    override fun onSelectionChanged() {
        if(selectionTracker!!.hasSelection()) {
            if(!actionModeOpened) {
                //Action mode first opened, disable NestedScrollView
                dissalow = true
            }
            actionModeOpened = true
        } else {
            //Action mode closed. Enable NestedScrollView to make scrolling work properly.
            dissalow = false
            actionModeOpened = false
        }
    }
})
```

The fix is not perfect (if you tap-and-hold and move your finger to the top or bottom of the screen, the contents won't scroll, because the `NestedScrollView` is kind of disabled), but it works much better than without the fix.